# Rails 3 subsequent forms submission (second dependent on first)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to achieve a subsequent form submission. To clarify things -

- I submit a form for @post
- then once that @post is created I would immediately (under the hood) like to submit the form for @associations.
- The catch is, this second form submission would require the post_id field from the newly created @post.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Would nested forms help me pull the newly created @post.id? Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Hosestly, I don't think you should do it this way. POST is supposed to represent a browser action toward the server, where the browser actually POST something to the server. What you want there is chain actions after sending your first form. Maybe you could give us a little more context for a more precise answer?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think the term @post created the confusion. I meant a model named "post" by that. So when I create a new entry in the "posts" model, I need to use the newly created post_id field in a new record for associations model subsequently. Hope this clarifies. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: In fact, the "I would immediately (under the hood) like to submit the form for @associations" sent me on the "post" track because when you submit a form, it's **usually** a POST we're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something that should happen whenever you create a `Post`, then you should use active callbacks to achieve that :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create do |post|
    # create your association using post.id
  end

end
```

or, you can write it like that also :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :after_create_post

  def after_create_post
    # create your association using self.id
  end

end
```

Otherwise, if this is something specific to a controller action, you should simple do something like this :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    # then use the @post.id to build your association. something like
    @post.associations.build(:prop1 => 'value1', :prop2 => 'value2')
  end

end
```

Hope this helps!